# Using add_image_size in functions.php to get original uploaded file

Tags: functions, images

It is possible to use add_image_size in functions.php to get the original uploaded file size. Because when I uploaded the images to my posts I cropped them in order to have 1x1 ratio for all my image sizes and I remember using the All images option.

So now when I use full or large I always end up with squared images. But I can see that the original uploaded files with the good proportions are still there in the uploads folder and I would like to use retrieve them if possible, somehow.

I use the following code in functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_attachment_all_images($postid=0, $size='full', $attributes='') {
    if ($postid<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $postid,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            ?><img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" alt="" class="imarge" /><?php
        }
}?>
```

But using 'full' for the size give me the cropped file not the original uploaded file. The output is:

myImageFile-e1343105908459.jpg (cropped 1x1)

instead of

myImageFile.jpg (original 3x2)

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the url for original attachment image. I don't see any code from you so i don't know which one is good for you but there are lots of functions on core which will get you the original image.

**here are some**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

When you scroll down bottom of the page you will see more related functions. So, searching on codex is always a good idea when you learning :)

Comment: Trying to use full doesn't work like I explained. It returns the cropped version.